# How can I call a webservice without adding it to Service References?

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-services

I saw this translator webservice
http://api.microsofttranslator.com/V2/Soap.svc

but I am not allowed to add a new web service to our application, it must only be called inside a Controller and there to use its method "Translate" and also pass the parameter so I can get the return string. Is there a way in doing this?

Thank you!

Comment: what language & compiler? please add appropriate tags.

Comment: I updated it, its c# asp.net MVC

Comment: what do you mean by "I am not allowed to add a new web service to our application"? (the following statements don't do much to clarify). Are you simply not allowed to make web-service calls to outside addresses? Or are you specifically not allowed to add something to your project? (say, a new reference).

Comment: not technical, but an order

Comment: could you explain in terms of the actual examples I gave?

Comment: also, you'd do much better if you showed some code.

Comment: I am not able to show codes, because... I don't know how to start with it. It is much easier for me to just add a Service Reference rather than doing this manually.

Comment: You still haven't explained the problem in a way that others here can understand. (We don't work there. We don't know your code. We don't know your policies). Show some of your code here (enough to reproduce the issue at least) will help people overcome that lack of understanding.

Comment: Not allowed to add something from our project - there
I just need to get the string translation from that service

Comment: Love it when organizations stipulate "we won't let you do it the easy way".  Anyway, a web service is nothing more than a web call, same as getting a web-page back.  So if you're going to have to do it manually, look at the `HttpClient` class.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thank you for all who response.

By the way here's the answer for my own question.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff512421.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Mentioning that you need to call the service from a controller suggests that you want to call it from inside code. You might call your service like shown [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd744834%28v=vs.95%29.aspx). Using the ChannelFactory gives you the ability to create your own service clients. You won't need to add a service reference to do that.

I also wrote a static wrapper making it easier to access services. Just ask if you need :-)

Comment: For the benefit of future visitors to this question... could you re-explain the OP's question and provide some reasoning behind your fix?